# Python, delete row from mysql not working

Tags: python, mysql, row, new-operator, radix

I'm trying to delete a selected item from `listbox`. This `listbox` is connected to a dabatase.
the problem is that delete is not working.
I have no error, but it not commit:

```
        def delete():
     
            row_delete = str(listbox.get(ACTIVE))                 
            cursor.execute("DELETE FROM database WHERE job=%s", (row_delete,))
            mydb.commit()
```

any idea?

Comment: can you ``print`` the value of row_delete? DELETE won't do anything if the value of row_delete isn't exactly the name of the job

Comment: What is the data type of the `job` column -- string or numeric?

Comment: add some data:

('1',) # No delete if i press delete
1  #yes delete

no delete case is an imported from database item.
yes delete case is when i insert from textbox and without closing app i press delete.

Comment: ok i use .replace('(','').replace(')','').replace(',','').replace("'","") to remove undiserable char. its very very very ugly -.-'